Can any one help/give tips on how to close this mesh's holes?
I'm relatively new to blender and extracted this model from a game and am trying to sculpt it to look like a friends character, editing the body shape and detailing it. though I'm running into an issue where once I try and sculpt it it ends up being very blocky, I was able to fix it by adding a "subdivision surface" modifier but when I do this it adds lots of holes into the model.
could someone give tips on how to fill these holes or make the model easier to sculpt? ty


Those holes are created from the subdivision rounding the corner of the mesh where it is not connected to the next part. You can see the same effect if you use a mirror modifier on a cube half and you put the subdivision modifier first before the mirror. Here I think you might need to use Multiresolution modifier using Simple subdivide if you intend on leaving the mesh disconnected as it is.

You also can merge the vertices (Edit mode, key M > Merge By Distance) or use a Weld modifier before (=above) the Subdivision Surface modifier. By the way, have you tried Shade Smooth? A level 3 Subdivision Surface modifier adds a lot of geometry and for sculpting it's not ideal because you can only sculpt only the base mesh (the mesh before the modifier generates the additional geometry) and it can result in bad performace. Try the Multiresolution modifier as suggested
